# What is containerView in animateTransition?

Tags: ios

```
UIView *fromView = fromVC.view;
UIView *toView = toVC.view;
UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
```

I really wonder what is the containerView? Is it the navigation controller's view?

Comment: Have you read the relevant [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerContextTransitioning_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerContextTransitioning/containerView)?

Comment: In this situation the containerView is ViewController. If you want to find more information about it  please check the doc of apple or raywenderlich.

Comment: @CuongNguyen, a `UIView` can't be a `UIViewController`... well, so the `containerView` is definitely __not__ the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The container view acts as the superview of all other views (including those of the presenting and presented view controllers) during the animation sequence. **UIKit sets this view for you and automatically adds the view of the presenting view controller to it**. The animator object is responsible for adding the view of the presented view controller, and the animator object or presentation controller must use this view as the container for all other views involved in the transition.